# Host name change breaking http? Fedora

Tags: iptables, http, fedora, httpd, hostname

OK so I have been messing around on my development server.
It has been a while since I have had my head in linux and I suspect I have broken something.

I have SSH running and that is working fine.

I also have HTTP and I had FTP running also.

Earlier today I decided I wanted to rename the machine so I updated the /etc/hosts file and /etc/sysconfig/network. I also changed the server name in the httpd.conf.

I rebooted the machine and reconnected to SSH fine.

Later I was messing around with the FTP service (trying to tighten up the user security) and when i tried to connect remotely to FTP no joy, it said cannot connect. I thought that was weird but had planned to remove ftp as we will be using github so removed ftp and moved on.

Then I tried to connect to the website but major fail. even connecting to the IP address is failing. I used lynx to connect to the localhost and there was my site so something going on at server level. I thought maybe something up with iptables but I have not changed them but tried adding http but still no joy.

I have a -

Fedora release 17 (Beefy Miracle)
NAME=Fedora
VERSION="17 (Beefy Miracle)"
ID=fedora
VERSION_ID=17
PRETTY_NAME="Fedora 17 (Beefy Miracle)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;34"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:fedoraproject:fedora:17"
Fedora release 17 (Beefy Miracle)
Fedora release 17 (Beefy Miracle)

Linux version 3.3.4-5.fc17.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-14.phx2.fedoraproject.org) (gcc version 4.7.0 20120504 (Red Hat 4.7.0-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Mon May 7 17:29:34 UTC 2012

This is my iptables -L

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Like I say I can use SSH no issue but http although running is a no go from a remote computer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you show us the output of `grep -ri Listen /etc/httpd/*`

Comment: Hey James,/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:Listen 80
Binary file /etc/httpd/modules/mod_cgid.so matches
Binary file /etc/httpd/modules/mod_info.so matches
Binary file /etc/httpd/modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so matches
Binary file /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so matches
Binary file /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5-zts.so matches

Comment: Nothing abnormal there. Is there anything relevant in the apache error log. path is something like `/var/log/httpd/error.log`

Comment: SSH, telnet all work fine so I think I have either stuff something up when I changed the hostname, messed up iptables without realising or something similar. DNS seems fine, I can ping the IP and the domain name etc

Comment: No nothing strange but as mentioned I can connect to the web service using lynx (text based browser) on the server connecting to local host it is only when I try to connect from a remote location it seems to be broken

Comment: IPtables is configured incorrectly. If the first rule fails to match the second rule will allow everything. This should not be preventing you from accessing port 80. The service failing to start is almost certainly a misconfiguration relating to the change of hostname except I can't tell where without some log info

Comment: OK looks like it was a missing rule in the iptables file. I added ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http and now all is good

Comment: Always the simple things, I thought i had tried this earlier but must not have saved or updated. thanks for your help though